# Browsersync in docker pod (docker-compose, laravel-mix)

Tags: laravel, webpack, docker-compose, laravel-mix, browser-sync

I am developing a laravel application with docker. In my pod i got a container vor the php-fpm process, a container for running nodejs (with npm run watch) and a container for nginx as a webserver along with other services like horizon, mailhog and so on.

Now i want to use laravel-mix (which i a webpack wrapper) together with browsersync for hot reloading. But i wont get it running.

I want to use (its a multi tenant app) local development domains with an ssl wildcard. The certificate and domain stuff works. But i am not sure how to set the values (proxy, host) for browsersync and where to expose the ports.

In my understanding the ports have to be exposed for the node service container. Defaults are 3000 and 3001 for the ui. If i do that and set my laravel-mix config like this i get a broken ui on http://mytestdomain:3001 and `ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE`on my external browsersync url `https://mytestdomain:3000`. I made sure that the ssl certificate is available in the specified location.

```js
mix.browserSync({
    proxy : 'devlocal_node', // not sure if this one should be container_name or service name
    host: 'mytestdomain.test',
    open: false,
    port: 3000,
    
    https: {
        key: '/ssl/mytestdomain.test.key',
        cert: '/ssl/mytestdomain.test.crt',
    },
    
});
```

The relevant parts of my docker-compose.yml

```
    # Application
    app:
        container_name: ${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}app
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: app.dockerfile
            target: app
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - "database"
    # Web Server
    web:
        container_name: ${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}webserver
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: web.dockerfile
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - app
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
    # node
    node:
        container_name: ${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}node
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: app.dockerfile
            target: nodeJS
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - type: bind
              source: ./Docker
              target: /dockerscripts
              read_only: true
            - type: bind
              source: ./ssl
              target: /ssl
              read_only: true
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
            - 3001:3001
        entrypoint: /dockerscripts/nodeservice.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok there are several things i got wrong in the beginning.

- Exposing the ports on the node container works in principle but by using ssl on my local development domain that will cause CORS errors. Instead the ports have to exposed by the webserver container. Subsequently there has to be a nginx config which sets a proxy pass to the node container for the ports 3000 and 3001.
  This vhost config sets the ssl certificate also.
- I am using inertia js in laravel. I had to add the browserscript script in my app template. Not sure if this should be done by inertia automatically without inertia.

So to sum this up I am attaching my current scripts.

Since browsersync now resides behind the web server the config has to be:

```
 mix.browserSync({
    proxy : 'http://node:3000', // name of the service in docker-compose.yml, running on http cause webservers handels encryption
    host: 'node', // ip of the service container
    open: false,
    port: 3000,
    logConnections: true, // not needed, debugging stuff
    logLevel: 'debug', // not needed, debugging stuff    
});
```

The relevant parts in docker-compose.yml

```
    # Application
    app:
        container_name: ${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}app
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: app.dockerfile
            target: app
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - "database"
    # Web Server
    web:
        container_name: ${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}webserver
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: web.dockerfile
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - app
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
            - 6001:6001
            - 9601:9601
            - 3000:3000
            - 3001:3001
    # node
    node:
        container_name: ${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}node
        #image: node
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: app.dockerfile
            target: nodeJS
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - type: bind
              source: ./Docker
              target: /dockerscripts
              read_only: true
        entrypoint: /dockerscripts/nodeservice.sh
```

The entrypoint script for the node container

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/www
# npm 
export NODE_ENV=development
npm install && npm run watch
```

Dockerfile for webserver container

```
FROM nginx:1.21

COPY vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY vhost_websocket.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/soketi.conf
# relevant browsersync vhost file
COPY vhost_browsersync.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/browsersync.conf

COPY ssl/mydomain.test.crt /var/www/ssl/mydomain.test.crt
COPY ssl/mydomain.test.key /var/www/ssl/mydomain.test.key

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Vhost file for browsersync

```
server {
    listen 3000 ssl http2;
    # force https-redirects
    #if ($scheme = http) {
    #    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    #}
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;
    server_name mydomain.test "~^(.*)?.mydomain.test";

    ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/mydomain.test.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/mydomain.test.key;

    # BrowserSync
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://node:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
server {
    listen 3001 ssl http2;
    # force https-redirects
    #if ($scheme = http) {
    #    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    #}
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;
    server_name mydomain.test "~^(.*)?.mydomain.test";

    ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/mydomain.test.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/mydomain.test.key;
    
    # BrowserSync UI
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://node:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```